# Some "footnote" appearing. I do not know how to modify it/ How it's called to properly google it

Tags: formatting

So I am trying to write some DnD stuff done using a template I found online (https://de.overleaf.com/latex/templates/d-and-d-5e-latex-template/vmfdkjfhfynv). It's been working great but I do really have trouble configuring it. If I disable the table of contents the part where there is "contents" at the bottom is just empty. I have no part in the code that's literally saying "contents" so it has to be somewhere lost in packages or configurations I think?

My main language sadly isn't english so researching it is kinda hard and in my mother tongue I didn't find anything -- sorry if it is a stupid questions.

Is there an option to either remove it completely or to type the text displayed in manually or to make the text always the same as the subsections?

And is there an option to correct it a couple of mm to the top side so that it isn't so tiny spaced?

[image: bottom of the page]

Comment: Please post a minimal, yet complete, code illustrating your problem.

Comment: What is your language? maybe you just need a language package